# my users table is missing in development and i can't figure out what happened

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, railstutorial.org

I'm working on Rails Tutorial and my users table keeps going missing in the middle of the exercise, even though I haven't touched it. Like it's just gone.

i've tried resetting the database, rake db:prepare, and the like but still no luck. any ideas would be awesome this is driving me crazy.

Here's the error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#new
Could not find table 'users'

Extracted source (around line #511):

        def table_structure(table_name)
          structure = exec_query("PRAGMA table_info(#{quote_table_name(table_name)})", 'SCHEMA').to_hash
          raise(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid, "Could not find table '#{table_name}'") if structure.empty?
          structure
        end
```

here's the full trace

```
Started GET "/apple-touch-icon.png" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:28:53 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/apple-touch-icon.png"):
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (225.8ms)


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:28:58 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (3.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 231ms (Views: 230.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:28:59 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (2.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 258ms (Views: 256.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:28:59 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 360ms (Views: 359.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:29:00 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (2.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 375ms (Views: 373.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/help" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:29:00 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#help as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/help.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 403ms (Views: 401.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:29:01 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (27.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 284ms (Views: 283.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:29:01 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (3.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 346ms (Views: 345.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:29:18 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (41.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 263ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1):
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `current_user'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:15:in `logged_in?'
  app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___2832195305809045204_70241069995700'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__577028620516446828_70241076070000'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (11.8ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (6.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (411.6ms)


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:31:53 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (5.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.2ms)
  User Load (3.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (154.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 573ms (ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1):
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `current_user'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:15:in `logged_in?'
  app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___2832195305809045204_70240806258820'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__577028620516446828_70241076070000'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (51.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (569.4ms)


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:09 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 182ms (Views: 180.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/custom.self-c38ac96984bc7e1251850a06b64c12df6b20e1117426706f1ca1b4cc7ad1586a.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:09 +0000


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.self-8e98a7a072a6cee1372d19fff9ff3e6aa1e39a37d89d6f06861637d061113ee7.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:09 +0000


Started GET "/assets/sessions.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:09 +0000


Started GET "/assets/static_pages.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:09 +0000


Started GET "/assets/users.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:09 +0000


Started GET "/assets/jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:09 +0000


Started GET "/assets/application.self-e80e8f2318043e8af94dddc2adad5a4f09739a8ebb323b3ab31cd71d45fd9113.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:09 +0000


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.self-cdea7efeac1597b89ddd6fd86b0e8e0bec5d5fb1fac9c6e8a045f2c59eef2d13.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:09 +0000


Started GET "/assets/static_pages.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:09 +0000


Started GET "/assets/application.self-7862a8a8b42407b4741a1adeeea35f0d13ddc4f702ec532adb0674491d296495.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:09 +0000


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.self-c846e670826600e8c91b1a5ada3e6547110d996cd6ff24cde55024f7a135a1b4.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:09 +0000


Started GET "/assets/users.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:09 +0000


Started GET "/assets/sessions.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:09 +0000


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:32:18 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (5.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (12.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 161ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1):
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `current_user'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:15:in `logged_in?'
  app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___2832195305809045204_70240802157820'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__577028620516446828_70241076070000'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (25.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (7.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (168.1ms)


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:33:42 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (3.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (22.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 241ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1):
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `current_user'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:15:in `logged_in?'
  app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___2832195305809045204_70240802157820'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__577028620516446828_70241076070000'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (34.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (9.7ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (176.9ms)


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:39:03 +0000
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (24.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 267ms (Views: 265.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/custom.self-c38ac96984bc7e1251850a06b64c12df6b20e1117426706f1ca1b4cc7ad1586a.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:39:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/static_pages.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:39:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/users.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:39:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/sessions.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:39:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/application.self-e80e8f2318043e8af94dddc2adad5a4f09739a8ebb323b3ab31cd71d45fd9113.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:39:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/sessions.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:39:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/users.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:39:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/static_pages.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:39:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/application.self-3b8dabdc891efe46b9a144b400ad69e37d7e5876bdc39dee783419a69d7ca819.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:39:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:39:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.self-8e98a7a072a6cee1372d19fff9ff3e6aa1e39a37d89d6f06861637d061113ee7.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:39:04 +0000


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.self-c846e670826600e8c91b1a5ada3e6547110d996cd6ff24cde55024f7a135a1b4.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:39:04 +0000


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:39:05 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (3.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 142ms (Views: 140.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:02 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (3.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 106ms (Views: 104.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/custom.self-c38ac96984bc7e1251850a06b64c12df6b20e1117426706f1ca1b4cc7ad1586a.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:02 +0000


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.self-8e98a7a072a6cee1372d19fff9ff3e6aa1e39a37d89d6f06861637d061113ee7.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:02 +0000


Started GET "/assets/sessions.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:02 +0000


Started GET "/assets/users.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/static_pages.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.self-c846e670826600e8c91b1a5ada3e6547110d996cd6ff24cde55024f7a135a1b4.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/users.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/sessions.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/application.self-3b8dabdc891efe46b9a144b400ad69e37d7e5876bdc39dee783419a69d7ca819.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/application.self-e80e8f2318043e8af94dddc2adad5a4f09739a8ebb323b3ab31cd71d45fd9113.css?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:03 +0000


Started GET "/assets/static_pages.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:03 +0000


Started GET "/signup" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:04 +0000
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:10:in `new'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (24.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (13.3ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (216.3ms)


Started GET "/signup" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:40:05 +0000
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:10:in `new'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (16.8ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (131.6ms)


Started GET "/" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:42:24 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (4.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 113ms (Views: 110.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/signup" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-06 21:47:22 +0000
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:10:in `new'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (24.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (31.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (8.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (220.2ms)


Started GET "/signup" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-07 14:42:08 +0000
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:10:in `new'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (37.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (6.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (8.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (195.4ms)


Started GET "/signup" for 71.125.40.81 at 2016-02-08 14:36:06 +0000
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 6.6ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:10:in `new'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (8.3ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (7.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (125.1ms)
```

Comment: Assume that nobody here has access to the tutorial, and explain your problem in that way.  Do you have a migration to create the table?  Have you copypasted any code about dropping the user table to any other migrations?  Do you create your db from scratch every time you run the tests?  What is in your test setup?

Comment: @MaxWilliams i believe my migrations are fine but I'm not sure. basically i was just working on then everything with the user table broke. so i need to figure out how to maybe reset it and get it working again. I'm new to rails and very lost at this point.

Comment: It sounds like you have either dropped the whole db and recreated it, or dropped the users table by accident.  Either way, run the migrations again.

Comment: Does it work after you run rake db:migrate?  How about after you run rake db:drop db:create db:migrate and db:seed(if you have seeds)

Comment: @ruby_newbie that did it! thank you thank you!!!